# Connecting product id between previous page link and new page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm almost there, but the id in this page listing product inventory:

```
<?php
while($productData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo '<a href="../product.php?id="'.$productData["id"].'">'.$productData["product_name"].'</a><br           />';
};
?>
```

won't connect with the product.php page code for some reason where I want to list details from the database of one product:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");

$p_sql = "SELECT * FROM products where id = '$id'";
$p_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $p_sql);

$prodData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

In the address bar it is showing as 'root/product.php?id=' with no product id number.

Comment: What does the href show on the page before you click it? Also don't have PHP variables in your SQL, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php.

Comment: My current presumption is that the href doesn't have the ID in it. This to me would indicate the productData doesn't have an 'id' in it. If this is the case what is the $p_query?